# session_destroy() + session_start() not after header redirect

Tags: php, session, session-variables, php-5.4

Trying to temporary store information in a multipage sign up. Because I don't want old sessions to mess with the new sign up data I'm trying to destroy the old session. The problem is the following.

**Not working:**

signup1.php

```
//Start new session
session_regenerate_id(TRUE);
session_destroy();
unset($_SESSION);
session_start();

//Store values in session
$_SESSION['created']    = time(); 

//Redirect to second step
header('Location: '.$settings->siteurl.'signup2.php');
exit();
```

signup2.php

```
<pre>
<?php 
    //Print $_SESSION (empty array)
    print_r($_SESSION); 
?>
```

**Working (but returns old $_SESSION values + updated values):**

```
//Start new session
session_regenerate_id(TRUE);

//Store values in session
$_SESSION['created']    = time(); 

//Redirect to second step
header('Location: '.$settings->siteurl.'signup2.php');
exit();
```

What could resolve the problem? First session_start(); is set in init.php but it doesn't matter if I place it above session_regenerate_id(TRUE), array stays empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this first:

```
session_start(); // Starts a new or resumes an existing session
```

Then you may use:

```
session_regenerate_id(TRUE); // regenerates the active session id
```

The `TRUE/delete_old_session` parameter is used for:

> Whether to delete the old associated session file or not.

The [session_regenerate_id](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php) is useful to prevent session hijacking and it just regenerates a new `id` but keeps session data. This should be used when user's access level changes or using a time interval (i.e. after every 10 minutes) but before you regenerate another new `session id` you need to start the session first.

Comment: Thanks! But how do I reset the session data for a user so that all values are new/cleared?

Comment: Do you want to destroy the session and it's data completely ?

Comment: Yes. Say that a user has already submitted the form once and has placed values in the session and has been redirected to page 2, I want them to be cleared if he submits the form again on page 1.

Comment: Then destroy the session on every form submission, i.e. `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { if(session_id() && isset($_SESSION['blah'])) { // destroy it} }`.